# ckeditor show me double style toolbar

Tags: ckeditor

I have this config:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {
        language : 'ru',
        toolbarGroups : [
            { name: 'history',   groups: [ 'redo', 'undo' ] },
            { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
            { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'align' ] },
            { name: 'links' },
            { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
        ]
    });
});
```

but if i try to set execatly items in 'styles', ckeditor show me double toolbar of styles:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried simply removing them? Meaning removing this part: `, items: [ 'Font', 'FontSize' ]`

Answer (score 0):

You confused `toolbarGroups` with `toolbar` setting. Toolbar groups should define only groups, not items like you do in the last group:

```
{ name: 'styles', items: [ 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
```

Replace this line with:

```
{ name: 'styles' },
```